# How to return two different lambda function depending on condition in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda

I am a beginner coder in C++. This is my code to return two different lambdas (with two different signatures) depending on condition.

```
function<int (int)> sum (int a, int b) {
  return [a, b](int c) {return a+b+c;};
}

function<int ()> constant (int x) {
  return [x](){return x;};
}

auto findResult (bool doSum, int number1, int number2) -> decltype(doSum ? sum(number1, number2) : constant(number1)) {
  if(doSum) {
   return sum(number1, number2);
  }else {
   return constant(number1);
  }
}
```

But I got the following errors. Am I doing something wrong?. I need some clarifications.

```
function<int (int)> sum (int a, int b) {
  return [a, b](int c) {return a+b+c;};
}

function<int ()> constant (int x) {
  return [x](){return x;};
}

auto findResult (bool doSum, int number1, int number2) -> decltype(doSum ? sum(number1, number2) : constant(number1)) { //Incompatible operand types ('function<int (int)>' and 'function<int ()>')
  if(doSum) {
   return sum(number1, number2); //No viable conversion from returned value of type 'function<int (int)>' to function return type 'int'
  }else {
   return constant(number1); //No viable conversion from returned value of type 'function<int ()>' to function return type 'int'
  }
}
```

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but how could `findResult` be a useful function as it is? Caller will not know what to do with the result - call it with a paremeter or not?

Comment: The return type must be the same.

Answer (score 1):

C++ programs have both compile time and runtime information in their state.

Runtime information is things like most variable values.  Compile time information is things like what type variables are.

You cannot convert runtime information into compile time information.  Which is what your code is trying to do.

Here, based off the runtime value of `doSum`, youwant to return either a function `int(int)` or a function `int()`.  That signature is compile time information.

There may be a way to solve your underlying problem, but you would first have to have described it.  As an example, you could return a `std::variant<std::function<int()>, std::function<int(int)>>`.  But it is also true you might be just making a design error here.

Comment: Depending on the usecase, could just make `doSum` a non-type template parameter and use `if constexpr`: https://godbolt.org/z/GzsEnx6o7

Comment: @PatrickRoberts and Yakk - Adam Nevraumont 
1. I am using C++ 14, So I cant use std::variant.
2. I cannot use constexpr also because the boolean value will be parsed from user input.

Is there any way to solve this problem in C++14 ?

Comment: @enola boost variant?  Rearchitect?  A callable with 2  incompatible signatures is a strange thing to want.